# Crystal Report made in VS2008, not opening in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I had a project in VS2008. It was deployed without a problem. However now I need to make some changes and upgraded that project to VS2012 (because VS2008 is not working).

In that project I have a Crystal report, but I am not able to open that in VS2012. When I open the report, all I see is numbers and letters.

Also tried deploying it on client machine; it just shows the report viewer and Crystal report is missing.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this, or do I need to build whole crystal report from scratch?

Comment: Yes..correct numbers and alphabets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP updates their drivers from time-to-time, to work with newer versions of Visual Studio.

Here is their landing page, with the current driver and a list of all older drivers:

- [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio: Updates & Runtime Downloads](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Here's a direct link to the latest installation package (SP9) for the Visual Studio IDE:

- [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_9.exe)

I'd close Visual Studio while installing the driver, but you shouldn't need to reboot afterwards.

Make sure you install the "install executable" (exe) file, not one of the msi files. That won't integrate Crystal into VS, as they mention on that page:

> Please note: To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" into VS 2010 or 2012 (SP 7 and higher) or VS 2013 (SP 9 or higher), you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only.